# I am trying to access element inside modal(mui modal) using ref in react but reference to element is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, ref, react-ref

I am trying to access in component did mount lifecycle method but its showing null.
If I remove the modal it's working as expected but inside modal ref is not working properly.
Thanks.
I have tried following but its showing null always.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  Backdrop,
  Fade,
  Container
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { contactUsFormSchema } from "../../constant/FormValidation";

class ContactUs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
    this.rootRef = React.createRef();
    this.childRef = React.createRef();
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries)=>{
      console.log(entries[0]);
    },{
      root:this.rootRef.current
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.childRef.current); // this is always null
    console.log(this.rootRef.current); // this is always null
    // this.observer.observe(this.childRef.current);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal
        open={true}
        onClose={this.props.handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500
        }}

      >
          <Container className={classes.modalStyle}  ref={this.rootRef}>
            <div className={classes.title} ref={this.childRef} >Contact US</div>
          </Container>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactUs;
```

Comment: It will always be `null` in `componentDidMount` since `createRef` is `async`. Have you tried using it later maybe on a click event?

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava if do not use modal it's working fine and I am able to access element.

Answer (score 0):

for those who are still facing the issue, i solved it by the following rule:

create a child component for the content inside modal and then use useRef or createRef within the child component.

Render the child component within modal.

It will work.

example is below (it is just a skeleton and not a working piece) Modal is a mui component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return (
            <div ref={yourReactRef}>
               <div>my content</div>
            </div>
        )
}

const ParentComponent = (props) => {
    return (
            <Modal>
                    <ChildComponent />
            </Modal>
        )
}
```